# Google Drive PDF Viewer sometimes not loading the pdf

Tags: pdf, viewer

I am using the google drive pdf viewer , using the codes below

```
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://xxx.xxxxx.com/download/testpdf.pdf" width="100%" height="375"></embed>
```

The strange thing is - it only works intermittently. I don't want to reply on googledrive. Is there any viewer scripts which I can install in my server so that I can use it as a substitute ? Please also share some example codes on using it if possible.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the js pdf viewer alternative. The pdf.js

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Below is the codes, you will need to

1. have the pdf.js in place
2. have the pdf.worker.js in place

put the codes below as say "viewer.php", and then you may use another php script to call "viewer.php?pdffile=test.pdf" and you are good to go.

Please note that old browsers may not work on this viewer. But current smartphone browsers will be ok.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

<style>
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #000000;
}

 
#the-canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  direction: ltr;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

</style>

 
<script src="./pdf.js"></script>

 
<div>  
<button id="prev">▲</button>
<button id="next">▼</button>
  &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>

 

<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

 

<script>

// If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
// header on that server.
var url = "<?php echo $_REQUEST["pdffile"]; ?>";
// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.

var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = './pdf.worker.js';

 
var pdfDoc = null,

    pageNum = 1,

    pageRendering = false,

    pageNumPending = null,

    scale = 5,

    canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),

    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 

/**

 * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.

 * @param num Page number.

 */

function renderPage(num) {

  pageRendering = true;

  // Using promise to fetch the page

  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {

    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

    canvas.height = viewport.height;

    canvas.width = viewport.width;

 

    // Render PDF page into canvas context

    var renderContext = {

      canvasContext: ctx,

      viewport: viewport

    };

    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

 

    // Wait for rendering to finish

    renderTask.promise.then(function() {

      pageRendering = false;

      if (pageNumPending !== null) {

        // New page rendering is pending

        renderPage(pageNumPending);

        pageNumPending = null;

      }

    });

  });

 

  // Update page counters

  document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;

}

 

/**

 * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is

 * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.

 */

function queueRenderPage(num) {

  if (pageRendering) {

    pageNumPending = num;

  } else {

    renderPage(num);

  }

}

 

/**

 * Displays previous page.

 */

function onPrevPage() {

  if (pageNum <= 1) {

    return;

  }

  pageNum--;

  queueRenderPage(pageNum);

}

document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

 

/**

 * Displays next page.

 */

function onNextPage() {

  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {

    return;

  }

  pageNum++;

  queueRenderPage(pageNum);

}

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

 

/**

 * Asynchronously downloads PDF.

 */

pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {

  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

 

  // Initial/first page rendering

  renderPage(pageNum);

});

</script>
```